# How to add background image to my phaser game?

Tags: html, phaser-framework

I want to add background image/ scene to my game. This code doesn't work.

```
        const config= {
            type: Phaser.AUTO,
            height: 675,
            width: 675,
            scene: {
                preload,
                create,
                update,
            }
        }
        const game = new Phaser.Game(config)
        const gameState ={
        }
        function preload() {
            this.load.image('background','/background.jpg');
        }
        function create() {
            gameState.move = this.add.circle(325,325,25,'0xffffff');
            let bg=this.add.image(0,0,'background');            
}

function update() {
}
```

What can I do? I am new to phaser gaming.
I don't think the URL is incorrect. But this is the output:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48sEI.png)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the URL of the image is incorrect. The [docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Loader.LoaderPlugin.html#image__anchor) say that the URL can be relative or absolute. If the image is on the same level in the file system with your JavaScript file, in your `preload` function you can try either:

`this.load.image('background','background.jpg');`

or

`this.load.image('background','./background.jpg');`